# Membrane Deflection

Tags: fluid-statics

Please forgive me if this problem has been addressed elsewhere.
In order to winterize my swimming pool, I cover it with plastic and weight the perimeter.
In the spring, it’s necessary to pump off the accumulated precipitation before removing the cover.

I wish to estimate the volume of water supported by the tarp.
I took a handful of graduate-level courses as a Pure Math BA, but I remember next to nothing about setting up and solving differential equations.

1. Assuming the plastic has stretched uniformly, and an infinitely long “rectangular” pool, how would I set up and solve a diffeq to determine the shape of the cross section? (Just out of curiosity—-assuming a parabolic cross section and half paraboloids at the ends has always worked well enough).
2. Can the community recommend a compact yet friendly advanced-undergrad text on diffeq and/or boundary value problems?